# Connect to Kafka cluster with Rust

Tags: rust, apache-kafka

I'm new to Rust. I'm trying to produce a message to Kafka cluster with authentication set up using Rust for example with the following credentials:

```
TopicList=random.topic
Servers=someserver:8080
KafkaKey=12kjdkjansd
KafkaSecret=asd21jaksdqjwdqkwd
SchemaRegistryURL=https://myrandom.confluent.cloud
SchemaRegistryKey=asdkjwdnewkeyasdqwd
SchemaRegistrySecret=casdkajwcrackthissecretasdkjawd
```

In Java, with Kafka standard library I can put it in with ease as these are their parameters:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
```

However, things are a bit more complicated with Rust. I have read through the library [rdkafka](https://docs.rs/rdkafka/0.29.0/rdkafka/config/struct.ClientConfig.html) and [kafka](https://docs.rs/kafka/0.9.0/kafka/) crates, but I couldn't see any set-up on configuration for schema key and secret. And also a few articles in Confluent, but I couldn't see anywhere where they add in these sets up.

Is there any sample code or articles which I can see as a reference on how to make this work?

Comment: https://docs.rs/rdkafka/latest/rdkafka/producer/struct.BaseProducer.html

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I can find where I should put bootstrap server, kafka apikey, and kafka secret, but not for schema registry

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

Comment: You can set all these options into rdkafka client for rust.

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems like there's no Rust support for SchemaRegistry

Comment: There is no Confluent Schema Registry support from Confluent. There is via https://crates.io/crates/schema_registry_converter. It should be 100% compatible with Java, else it's considered a bug.